# Do i need to flush OPCACHE during update magento

Tags: php, magento2, opcache

I updated my magento and also the (PHP) frameworks with it, a verry simple question where i can't find the answer.

Do i need to flush/clear the OPcache during (before of after) an update of the PhP frameworks?

Is it possible that when i don't do it that there are corrupt files or errors showing up?

Comment: Whether or not you need to flush the OPCache really depends on your cache policy. If your cache is set to check file headers for changes then you don't need to flush it no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your opcache configuration (php.ini), have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/opcache.configuration.php).

See particulary :

- [opcache.validate-timestamps](http://php.net/manual/fr/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.validate-timestamps)
- [opcache.revalidate-freq](http://php.net/manual/fr/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.revalidate-freq)

If you enable revalidate, you never have to invalidate manually your opcache.

PS : if you disable invalidation, you have to clear opcache after updating your sources.

Comment: Thanks, i did the checks and the setting are correct. No flushing is nescessery